# Interesting symbol in a piece of piano music

Tags: theory, notation

A friend sent me this image and asked me to identify the symbol circled in red. I tried using Google Lens but no luck. Thanks for your help!
[image]

Comment: While I haven't seen this symbol before, I'll make a guess. Perhaps the symbol in question is a type of da capo al segno or dal segno, etc. This could be checked by finding a jump to this section.

Comment: Is there any chance of getting additional information from your friend? At the top of my list would be knowing the source of the music (that is, link to a web site, or the name of the book/publisher where this came from).

Comment: It *looks* somewhat like a sort of "segno", but it's standing in the middle of the third bar of the main "Jurassic Park" theme. That's not a place that you'd typically jump back to.

Comment: It means “Beware of raptor with one eye bigger than the other.“ Or decapitated snowman.

Comment: Can you provide a image that shows a bit more context?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm voting to close the question as it is. Short answer, no, this is not a commonly recognized musical symbol. I'm guessing the full page would have had an explanatory note somewhere about what it was supposed to mean. If you can post the full page, or even perhaps give a hint as to the arrangement (is this an instrumental part from a band arrangement?), there might be a trail to follow; in the meantime, there's not enough to go on.

Comment: This symbol looks a lot like the symbol used for an "Indian drum clef", but whether this makes any sense in this case is impossible to tell without more context.

Comment: It's not a standard notation. If you show us the complete page of music perhaps we can take a guess at what its intention is. Or possibly it's a misprint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw this [same question](https://www.facebook.com/groups/musicengravingtips/permalink/3062233200742218/) recently in the Music Engraving Tips group on Facebook.
The consensus seems to be that it's definitely the symbol for Indian Drum Clef, but what it's doing there in this score is questionable.  May be just an error.  (Your post uses the exact same image as that post, so maybe that post was from your friend and he wasn't happy with this answer.)

Comment: Just doing a Google image search for "tabla notation" brings up many examples and even [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RyDIL4V2WKU).  The glyph apparently represents a pair of tablas graphically.  The Jurassic Park example does seem to be a misapplication.